# App crash: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my tableView

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        print("numberOfsection Call")
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("numberOfRows Call")
        if places.count < self.numberPlaces {
           return  places.count
      }
       return self.numberPlaces
    }
```

the application is going in a crash for this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update

after I added this animation

```
    func insertRowsMode3() {            
        numberPlaces = 0
        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
    }

    func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        numberPlaces = ind + 1
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        guard ind < places.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }

    }
```

What is wrong whit it? There is a way to create the same animation that does not crash the app?

**UPDATE**

```
public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resueIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.myCellNumber.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.refButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CourseClass2.reloadCell(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let place = sortedArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

         if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            CarTo(false)
        }
        print("CellForRow Call")
        return (cell)

       }
```

Comment: what wrong is: you don't update your datasource.

Comment: is only that the problem? how can i update the datasource?

Comment: when you insert a new row into the table-view, you need to insert a new record into your datasource as well – keeping them synchronised.

Comment: and how you do it this?

Comment: Can you show your _:cellForRowAt: function?

Comment: @fisherM, I don't understand your question... your model seems to be the `places` (probably _Array_) where (probably) the `self.numberPlaces` is derived from as well...

Comment: I updated the question, yes places is  var places: [QPlace] = []

Comment: maybe the array must to be filled before i insert the rows?

Comment: my array sortedArray is = to the array places

Comment: Has there been any solution yet? I also have the same problem